# how to create an isometric background image with a tilemap or some other technique

Tags: game-engine, isometric

The background image should cover the viewport. The technique I use now is a loop with an innerloop that draws diamond shaped images on a canvas element, but it looks like a rotated square.

This is a nice example: [Plants vs Zombies](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/492440540476573568/),that covers the whole viewport.

I have read something about clickthrough maps, but is that all?

Any advice in grid design out there?.

Comment: Seen the excellent answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892811/drawing-isometric-game-worlds? What have you "read on clickthrough maps"? Clicking "on" an isometric tile instead of on its bounding box, as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259651/html-js-css-isometric-grid-with-semi-transparent-click-through-tiles?

Comment: thankyou, I put those posts into my favorites